# how to send email using c++ without specifying smtp server

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smtp

I want to send email over SMTP using c++ code, how should I handle it in generic way that a random user don't have to handle SMTP server specification? (Windows)

Without specification means user should not have to write IP address of SMTP server etc.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding of the concept of how E-Mail work. The SMTP server is the server that handles the outgoing mail, it will deliver the mails to the respective recipient servers. Unless you want to code your _own_ smtp server, you have to know one to relay your mails somewhere.

Comment: So you are saying writing my own is the best option for not specifying....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install an smtp relay server on the same host where the code runs and set the SMTP server in the code to 'localhost'.

Comment: can i manage this all you are reffering through coding if yes plz guide little bit

Comment: Zeeshan, what have you tried so far?  What commands/library in C++ are you using to send mail?

Comment: @nicholasM uptil now i have googled, i found that you one can use smtp servers of others like gmail,yahoo etc, or you have to specify it on other pc having smtp server installed, but my problem is i want to deliver code to my friend , he demands no dlls, and no specifying of SMTP server on GUI(he want me to generically handle this) so all i want is the above two points, so can you tell me achieve that exactly

Answer (score 1):

Jasper's answer is correct.  You need to install an SMTP server on the host that your C++ program is running on.  One option is qmail.  See www.lifewithqmail.org for more info, including a step-by-step guide on how to install it.

Most linux SMTP servers (including qmail) will create a smylink /usr/sbin/sendmail which you can use to send an outgoing message.  In general, the syntax is:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail recipient@domain.tld < /path/to/file/containing/the/message
```

See the help file for more info, including flags that you can use to specify the envelope sender, etc.

You can send a message from your C++ program by doing a system call to /usr/sbin/sendmail similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Simple MAPI, but you need an email program supporting the MAPI-interface like Outlook.